# How to animate to a specific position of a gallery

Tags: android, gallery

I would like move to a specific position in a gallery with animation. For example, I have 100 elements in a gallery and the actual position is 0. I would like to move slowly (animated) to position 99.

I tried the following command, which seemed promising. But it does not animate :-(

```
gallery.setSelection(int position, boolean animate)
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to use something like this:
create animate.xml file

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     android:shareInterpolator="true">
<translate 
    android:fromXDelta="0%p" android:toXDelta="50%p" // change this to decide the range
    android:duration="500" android:startOffset="0"/>
<translate 
    android:fromXDelta="0%p" android:toXDelta="100%p" 
    android:duration="500" android:startOffset="500"/>
```

and in your code use this:

```
Animation inFromRight =  AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.animate);
gallery.startAnimation(inFromRight);
gallery.setSelection(PicPosition);
```

The idea is from this link:

[Android gallery slideshow animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7090939/android-gallery-slideshow-animation)

Comment: Thanks. Can I do this programmatically ? ( without a static xml definition ) 0-99 was only an example.
I would like to jump dynamically to any position. 5-60 , 90-10 etc...